# How to get relative URL from current URL

Tags: twig, shopware

I am new with Shopware 6 and its template engine Twig, but I need relative URL from current URL in theme. The problem is that almost all data in database are binary, so if I use:

`{{ app.request.pathInfo }}`
or
`{{ app.request.requesturi }}`

I always get such output:

`/detail/eccbc87e4b5ce2fe28308fd9f2a7baf3`

but the current URL in browser is a search friendly URL.

With:
`{{ seoUrl('frontend.detail.page', { productId: page.product.id }) }}` 
I get the absolute URL in a search friendly format, but every try to replace host and scheme fails and I get an error. I can only replace /, detail or eccbc87e4b5ce2fe28308fd9f2a7baf3, but not host and not scheme.

Does anybody know what to do to get relative URL?

Comment: Can you describe your usecase in more detail? In general the `seoUrl` function will only render a placeholder, this placeholder later will be replaced by the configured seoUrl for that salesChannel and that language of the request. That is why you can't manipulate the host in twig, because the host will only be resolved after the twig rendering is done.

Comment: Okay, I understand. The usecase is that I have a webserver driven HTTP cache. For this I use its ESI function in theme. To define ESI tags I need the relative URL for name and src attribute like <esi:inline name="/relative_url" .....> and <esi:include src="/relative_url" ....> for the requested URL. But again and related to seoUrl the name of the URL comes database table seo_url, where it is stored in plain text.  I don't think that there is something to resolve.

Answer (score 2):

Solution: `{{ app.request.attributes.get('sw-original-request-uri') }}`